Writing float variables to sqlite3 db
When using the float variables no values are saved in db.
char *sql = "INSERT INTO Readings (C02, TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY) VALUES ($co2, $temp, $hum);";

47|||
48|||

When using values float values in they are entered into db.
char *sql = "INSERT INTO Readings (C02, TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY) VALUES (833.42, 23.11, 40.25);";

45|833.42|23.11|40.25
46|833.42|23.11|40.25


You should learn how to use prepared statements with parameters rather than substituting values directly into the SQL string.

Can we see how you're executing this SQL? Generally you need to call an execute method and pass in parameters.

@EricPostpischil One of the syntaxes sqlite accepts for named parameters is $foo, so that's a perfectly acceptable statement to prepare. You'd use sqlite3_bind_parameter_index() to get the appropriate parameter index for a name and then sqlite3_bind_double() etc. to give it a value.

char *sql = "INSERT INTO Readings (C02, TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY) VALUES ($co2, $temp, $hum);";
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);

Thanks Barmar, got code working sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 1, co2);
sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 2, temp);
sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 3, hum); prepared statements

@Dave Please go ahead and self-answer your question with the working code and an explanation. This will be useful for others.

int addRec(float co2, float temp, float hum){
    printf("insert");
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *err_msg = 0;
    int rc = sqlite3_open("Data.db", &db); 
    
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);  
        return 1;
    }   
    
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    const char* insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Readings (TIMESTAMP, CO2_PPM, TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insertQuery, -1, &stmt, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);        
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;

    }   
    
    const char* timeStamp = time_stamp();
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, timeStamp,-1,SQLITE_STATIC);
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 2, co2);
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 3, temp);
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 4, hum);
    
    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
 
    }
    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);        
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;

    }
    
    sqlite3_reset(stmt);
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}


An explanation would make this a better answer, such as references to the applicable documentation.
